# How to automatically include dependencies of Java Project when being added as Deployment Assembly of Dynamic Web Project

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, web-applications, classpath

I have two projects, where one is a java-project (framework-collection with functinalities) and the other one a dynamic web project which consumes these functions.

My framework uses org.joda.time (JodaTime) to check if a Date is "today", "tomorrow" etc. (date to string calculations). I have checked the "export" box in the framework and have included the project in my webapps' classpath. I also did the "deployment assembly" hints from here. The Sourecode builds without problems.

Now, when I start the project, it works fine, until the framework is used the first time (not joda but also any other method in the same class-no matter which one), it gives me:

```
Sep 08, 2014 8:39:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/LogbookOnline] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.ReadableInstant
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at com.ks.logbook.controller.functions.Functions.loadLogbookRights(Functions.java:463)
```

the loadLogbookRights() has nothing to do with joda, but it uses a method of the framework which is in the same class as the joda time functionalities (it closes DB-connections: FrameworkUtils.closeConnections(...)).

I don't know what to do. When I copy the "joda-time-methods" into my webapp it works (and remove them from the framework). just when I try to use them (or even any method in the same class) from the frameworke project it crashes...

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with

> When I copy the "joda-time-methods" into my webapp it works

but of course you need to add your libraries to the WAR to make them accessible to Tomcat.  For, you simply put the libs into the `lib` directory:

> The `WEB-INF/lib/` subdirectory can store JAR files used by the Web module. The JAR files in this directory are automatically accessible to the Web module without needing to be added to the class path.

([Source](http://documentation.progress.com/output/Iona/orbix/6.1/tutorials/fnb/dev_intro/j2ee_overview8.html))